# finding the sum of an arraylist but excluding the largest element

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, sum

I currently don't have any code , but I need to return the sum of an arraylist but without including the largest element, for example , 3,4,5,10, I would have to find the sum of 3+4+5 which =12.
I have no idea how to write the code so that it ignores the largest element.
I've currently got :

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   sum = sum + array[i];
return sum;
```

Comment: Iterate over all elements, sum them and at the same time check for maximal value. After iteration subtract max from sum.

Comment: first need to find the largest element. There are various ways, and one is to sort the List ascending. After just sum till last but one (last is the largest) ...

Answer (score 1):

I this problem as a simple combination of two problems:

1. Sum all the elements of a collection
2. Find the largest element in a collection

You could probably do both in a single iteration over your collection:

- sum elements one by one, keep track of the highest so far
- once done, subtract the highest to the total sum

But there are many other ways as stated in comments or answers; just find the one you think fits the most your logic.

Answer (score 0):

### Approach

Compute the full sum, then compute the max element and subtract it from the full sum:

```
List<Integer> values = List.of(3, 4, 5, 10);

int sum = 0;
for (int value : values) {
    sum += value;
}

int max = Collections.max(values);

sum -= max;
```

---

### Single iteration

You can of course also compute both in one go:

```
List<Integer> values = List.of(3, 4, 5, 10);

int sum = 0;
int max = values.get(0);
for (int value : values) {
    sum += value;
    if (value > max) {
        max = value;
    }
}

sum -= max;
```

---

### Streams

And you can also use the `Stream` API to do the job. `IntStream::summaryStatistics` computes everything needed efficiently in one go:

```
List<Integer> values = List.of(3, 4, 5, 10);

IntSummaryStatistics stats = values.stream()
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
    .summaryStatistics();

int sum = stats.getSum() - stats.getMax();
```

Also very helpful if you have a very large list of data (> 10k) as it provides multithreading out of the box.

Comment: Obviously "efficiently" in the case of streams is more on code brevity, not efficient code.

Comment: @trilogy Efficiently in the sense of _"everything in one iteration"_.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Sum {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //arr size>1
        int arr[] = {3,5,4};
        int res[] = getSumAndMax(arr);
        
        int sum=0;
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++)
        {
            sum+=arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println("sum="+sum+" :max="+arr[arr.length-1]);
        System.out.println("sum="+res[0]+" :max="+res[1]);
    }
    public static int[] getSumAndMax(int[] arr)
    {
        int sum=0;
        int max=arr[0];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            sum+=arr[i];
            max = Math.max(max, arr[i]);
        }
        int out[] = {sum-max, max};
        return out;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
sum=7 :max=5
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but when i say Arrays.sort(array); , it says cannot find anything named "Arrays"?

Comment: have to import first the class, it's not by default in `java.lang` ... `import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: thank you so much for your help, apparently i didnt need to sort the array , i just had to do length-1 like you said. I LOVE THIS WEBSITE

Comment: :) , if it's not sorted you get the right answer if you were lucky enough to have `max` on last position ...(sort enforce max on last position)

Comment: also note that sort is time consuming, so even if you got the right answer with maybe computing max with the calculation of sum and deduct at the end is faster ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

- set sum and max to first value.
- then iterate and compute sum and find max.
- then return sum less the value max.

```
public static int findSum(int[] array) {
    if (array == null || array.length <2){
            return 0;
    }
    int max = array[0];
    int sum = max;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        int v = array[i];
        sum = sum + v;
        if (v > max) {
            max = v;
        }
    }
    return sum - max;
}
```

And here is a way to do it with streams.

- stream the ints
- invert the bits (complement operator ~)
- sort them
- skip the first one
- invert them again
- sum.

The inverting of the bits is an old trick that allows them to be sorted in equivalent reverse order since an `IntStream sorted` method does not take a `Comparator`. Then skip the first element which would be the largest, invert them again to their original value and then sum the remainder.

```
public static int findSumStream(int[] array) {
    return array == null || array.length < 2 ? 0 : Arrays
            .stream(array)
            .map(i -> ~i)
            .sorted()
            .map(i->~i)
            .skip(1)
            .sum();
    
}
```